# Deleting multiple files in Linux?

Tags: linux, rm

How can I delete multiple files in Linux created at same date and time? How can I manage this without using date? The file have different names.

I have these .txt files:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root        54 Jan  6 17:28 file1.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root        33 Jan  6 17:28 file2.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root        24 Jan  6 18:05 file3.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root         0 Jan  6 17:28 file4.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root         0 Jan  6 17:28 file5.txt
```

How can I delete all the files with one command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simply use `rm -f file*.txt` to delete all files which starts with file and ends with the extention `.txt`

Comment: thnx.. Its working but there is one problem terminal asks everytime while removing

rm: remove regular file `file1.txt'?
rm: remove regular file `file2.txt'?
rm: remove regular file `file3.txt'?
rm: remove regular empty file `file4.txt'?
rm: remove regular empty file `file5.txt'?

is there any attribute or solution to this??
i mean why it asked for each n every time
it will cost to much time for processing delete operation on huge amount of files as it will asks every time to remove file

is there any equivalent solution??

Comment: use the Option -f --> `rm-rf file*.txt` so you will not get the question anymore.

Comment: thnx.. now its on actual track ..  :-)

Comment: @Jens `rm -f file*.txt` is enough, why he needs `-r`ecursive flag? He is deleting files, not directories.

Answer (score 4):

You can use find command and specify the time range. In your example: if you would like to find all files with modified timestamp from 6. Jan 17:28 you can do something like:

```
find . -type f -newermt '2016-01-06 17:28' ! -newermt '2016-01-06 17:29'
```

if you would like to delete them, just use finds exec parameter:

```
find . -type f -newermt '2016-01-06 17:28' ! -newermt '2016-01-06 17:29' -exec rm {} \;
```

you can also include -name '*.txt' if you want to process only *.txt files, and check maxdepth parameter as well if you would like to avoid processing subdirectories

Answer (score 0):

If you know the minutes of the file modified then you can deleted all files using `find` command. consider the file was last modified ten minutes ago. Then you can use,

```
find -iname "*.txt" -mmin 10 -ok rm {} \;
```

If you don't need to prompt before deleting then use `-exec`.

```
 find -iname "*.txt" -mmin 10 -exec rm {} \;
```

If you need to delete the files using access time then you can use `-amin`